# FLUTTER: " Undefined name 'manSoMi' "

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to call a final variable name "manSoMi" in AssetImage Widget but it always gets an error. I've tried many solutions to solve an error but it always says "Undefined name 'manSoMi'

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:zeus_app/models/Somiproduct.dart';

class DetailProductCart extends StatefulWidget {
  final SoMiNam manSoMi;
   const DetailProductCart({super.key, required this.manSoMi});
  
  @override
  State<DetailProductCart> createState() => _DetailProductCartState();
}

class _DetailProductCartState extends State<DetailProductCart> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
                width: size.width,
                height: 500,
                decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage(manSoMi.image),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover)),
              ),
       
      ],
    )
  
    );
  }

}
```

This is a Product class that i want to call it in AssetImage Widget by using the index name  "manSoMi.image"

```
class SoMiNam {
  final String image, title, addColors, price;
  final int id;
  SoMiNam(
      {required this.image,
      required this.title,
      required this.addColors,
      required this.price,
      required this.id});
}

List<SoMiNam> aoSoMi = [
  SoMiNam(
      title: 'Sunflower Polo Tee',
      price: '399.000 đ',
      image: 'assets/images/v1.jpeg',
      addColors: '+3 màu',
      id: 1),
  SoMiNam(
      title: 'Bei Linen Shirt',
      price: '429.000 đ',
      image: 'assets/images/v6.jpeg',
      addColors: '+3 màu',
      id: 2),
  SoMiNam(
      title: 'GodFather Shirt',
      price: '449.000 đ',
      image: 'assets/images/v8.jpeg',
      addColors: '+4 màu',
      id: 3),
  SoMiNam(
      title: 'Felix Shirt',
      price: '449.000 đ',
      image: 'assets/images/FelixShirt.JPG',
      addColors: '+2 màu',
      id: 4),
  SoMiNam(
      title: 'Hemi Shirt',
      price: '419.000 đ',
      image: 'assets/images/HemiShirt.JPG',
      addColors: '+1 màu',
      id: 5),
  SoMiNam(
      title: 'Lala Cuban Shirt',
      price: '449.000 đ',
      image: 'assets/images/LalacubanShirt.JPG',
      addColors: '+2 màu',
      id: 6),
];
```

This is an error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `widget.manSoMi` in order to access your variable in state full widget.

Comment: I'm glad that help you. If it was the answer you want ,please approve it so other people find it easy.

Comment: Yes, i'll do it

Answer (score 1):

You need to use widget:

```
   widget.manSoMi.image;
```

To access varieble manSoMi of DetailProductCart in _DetailProductCartState class.

Comment: You, welcome! Have a nice flutter experience!